# How do I convert a boolean JSON literal to a numeric target type or ignore it using Gson?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I'm trying to parse JSON object with Retofit and Gson deserializer. Here is an example of my json:

```
{
    "1": {
      "name": "Joe",
      "age": 50
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": 3
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "Brad",
      "age": false
    }
}
```

As you can see, Brad's age is **false**, so Retrofit service throws an exception:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected an int but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 188134 path $..age`
How can I ignore all the items with not expected types?

Comment: How does your question title summarize up your problem briefly? What is so special in column `188134`? Nothing. Please be concrete as much as possible to lower noise. What you need here is a your custom type adapter for the `age` field (and probably its type in general) that deserializes it to the target type value or ignores the actual deserialization result if it does not fit the target type. Or, better, ask your JSON source provider to fix their broken API to let it be correct letting your code be smooth.

Comment: you can define `age` as `String` or `Any` and handle explicitly

Comment: @sidgate The OP _can_ do that but don't you think that the suggestion is bad? Why using incorrect types to work around an issue Gson type adapters are for? `String` will obviously bring issues holding any JSON primitive (note it would only work because Gson has some its long-living quirks). Making it `Any` is even worse because the OP would never know the deserialized type unless doing a concrete type check (making it `Any` would accept even `[...]` and `{...}` which is just bad).

Comment: Adding to fluffy's comment: Gson's [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation might be helpful here to only customize deserialization for that specific field (and not for `int` in general).